# How to get output in format of list using mongodb and Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java and mongoDB to get sum of values of specific key.

Here is my work around:

```
ArrayList<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();
JSONArray networkCapacityTrending = new JSONArray();
BasicDBObject cmdBody = new BasicDBObject("aggregate",networkRealtime.toString());
BasicDBObject match = new BasicDBObject();
//set query to DB 

pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$match", match));
pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$group",
new BasicDBObject("_id", "$runtimeMillis").append("total",
new BasicDBObject("$sum", "$totInOutOctets")))));
pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$sort", new BasicDBObject("_id", 1)));
cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline);

// Put db command for execution in json array
networkCapacityTrending.put(db.command(cmdBody));
JSONObject obj;
JSONArray result = new JSONArray();
try {
    obj = networkCapacityTrending.getJSONObject(0);
    result = obj.getJSONArray("result");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Logger.error("Error while getting network capacity trending "
    + e.getMessage());
}
```

It gives me output as :

```
[{_id: 1403259854796,total: 0},{_id: 1403259896382,total: 0},{_id: 1403265301824,total: 0}]
```

but I wants output as 
    [[1403259896382,30],[1403259854796,10],[1403259854996,50]...]

how do I query to documents to get desired output???

Comment: Process the result by iterating over the children of the list and create a string containing the ID and the total value appended. Where exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to iterate your `JSONArray` and form a List like this:

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>> final_arr = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Long>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Long> array_int = new ArrayList<Long>();
            int aInt = result.getJSONObject(i).getInt("total");
            array_int.add(result.getJSONObject(i).getLong("_id"));
            array_int.add(new Long(aInt));
            final_arr.add(array_int);
        }
   System.out.println(final_arr);
```

In the above code, `result` is `JSONArray` with value : `[{_id: 1403259854796,total: 0},{_id: 1403259896382,total: 0},{_id: 1403265301824,total: 0}]` as mentioned in the question.

And the `final_arr` contains the desired output: `[[1403259854796, 0], [1403259896382, 0], [1403265301824, 0]]`

Comment: But I want output as [[1403259896382,30],[1403259854796,10],[1403259854996,50]...]

Comment: @user3322141 the output is coming the format you want, run and check.

Comment: @user3322141 are you talking about the format of your output or the values??

Comment: about format of output. I want to use this output to draw a chart on webpage

Comment: I don't want keys _id and total in data

Comment: @user3322141 did you run and check the code i wrote?? Its doing that only.